# Wordpress loop: Display <div> if posts exist

Tags: loop, query, array, variables, id

In a single post template I am trying to output some header text in a `<div>` and display links to related posts in a `<ul>` if related posts exist (based on tags). If there are no posts, nothing should be displayed. `$idspost[] = $post->ID` gets the posts which should be displayed. The loop is one of a series of loops and the retrived post ID's are also passed on to the next loop in order to avoid duplicate posts showing up. All works well so far. I have echoed out the ID's to test, but with my basic skills I don't realize how I will display the `<div>,<ul>` and retrieve the post ID's in the standard way:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
  <div>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      … //get the permalink, title etc...
    <?php endwhile; ?> 
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The post ID's are retrieved:

```
<?php
    $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
    if ($tags) {
      $second_tag = $tags[1]->term_id;
      $args=array(
        'tag__in' => array($second_tag),
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
        'showposts'=>5, //Display this number of related posts
        'ignore_sticky_posts'=>1
       );
      $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
      if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
          while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
          if (!in_array($post->ID, $ids)) 
          {; $idspost[] = $post->ID; ?>

    <?php }
        $ids[]= $post->ID; 
        $idspost[] = $post->ID;
        endwhile;
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Would be very grateful for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the data in the array to output as posts I did the following:

```
<?php
  if(count($idspost)){
    echo "<div>Related posts<ul>";
    foreach($idspost as $id){
       echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink( $id ).'">'.get_the_title( $id ).'</a></li>';
    }
    echo "</ul></div>";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the has_tag function in a conditional statement to achieve what you want. Take a look at the codex page here:
[Function Reference/has tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_tag).
This isn't 100% tailored to your specific question, but you should see how it's working and adjust for your specific task:

```
<?php if( has_tag() ) { ?>
<?php query_posts( 'cat=1&posts_per_page=5' ); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 
<div id="has-tags">
    <ul id="the-tags"><?php the_tags(); ?></ul>
  <?php the_content(); ?>
  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
<?php
} else { 
// Whaterver else you're doing here.'
} ?>
```

Comment: Thank you Jeremy! I found a working solution by using an if condition and foreach to grab the data stored in the `$idspost` array